# How to get next month same day on a given date in javascript (Not JQuery)

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on calendar booking and if a client booked an event to occur on monthly basis but same day the first , then I will mark the calendar the same day next month based on the start booked date. Please see below for more details:

Example:
 given date = 2018-09-18 (3rd Tuesday) (start booked date)
 desired output dates:
   - (2018-10-16) (3rd Tuesday)
   - (2018-11-20) (3rd Tuesday)

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any effort

Comment: What if there is no such date? This February didn't have a fifth Wednesday for instance, though January did. Incomplete spec to work from…

Comment: Sorry if you find this topic off-topic or no efforts given. I was just asking for any idea. Tried to solve this for hours and still not giving me the right path. I'm asking a favor to please not close this post. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Take an example and show us what you tried. Here https://wiki.base22.com/btg/how-to-compare-dates-in-javascript-81791002.html you have an example working with dates in js

Comment: a tricky thing would be to use a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get the day (monday, tuesday, ...) and going backward day by day to the first to count the number of time this day appear. Then to create a `Date` at the start of next month and add one day at a time until the solution is found

Comment: Please edit your question and ad the code you tried, and show the problems you faced :)

Comment: Sorry if no code was provided, please see below accepted answer. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

Add this to you project once:

```
Date.prototype.AddMonth = function (i) {var dy=this.getDay(); this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + i * 1); this.setDate(this.getDate() - (this.getDay()-dy)); return this; };
```

now use it similar this everywhere:

```
(new Date()/*your date*/).AddMonth(1/*MonthCount*/);
```

---

**New Approach (Using function):**

If you don't want to use prototype, try this:

```
function AddMonth(date, i) {var dy=date.getDay(); date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + i * 1); date.setDate(date.getDate() - (date.getDay()-dy)); return date; };
```

Usage:

```
AddMonth(new Date("2018/09/18"), 1);
```

Comment: This is not exactly what Op want, he want to go from 3rd Monday of the month to 3rd Monday of next month. not going form 3rd of month to 3rd of next month

Comment: @jonatjano thanks! you saved me.. really really thanks!

Comment: @Tony I just reviewed it, HassanSadeghi made all the work (I still can't find out how it works :/)

Comment: @HassanSadeghi even if it works it is still a bad idea to modify a prototype

Comment: you don't need use prototype. you can use it as a simple function. but, thank you for your honesty @jonatjano.

Comment: your welcome @Tony. I'm glad your problem was resolved. I solved the problem myself, do you remove your up vote?

Comment: @HassanSadeghi it may be some down vote because mine is still yours. SO community is prone to downvote on solution modifying prototype

Comment: no @HassanSadeghi, I up voted your answer. Not sure why it is still 0. sorry about that :(

Comment: If you would like to use the `function` instead of `prototype`, try the new way I've added. :)

Comment: your welcome @Tony. that added part was another example for @jonatjano to show him how to do this work via `function` instead of `prototype`.